# Function inside Object not returning value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm attempting to write some code that runs over an array of `lessons` within the object below and return the percentage of completed lessons (ones marked as `completed: true`).

When I `console.log` the outcome it just shows as `[Function completion]`, rather than a number as expected. Where am I going wrong?

For reference I'm using JS with React Native, but this should only concern JS if I'm correct?

**WorkoutCategoryData.js**

```
export default [
  {
    title: "Title 1",
    subtitle: "Subtitle 1",
    lessonCount: 4,
    lessons: [
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 1",
        completed: true
      },
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 2",
        completed: true
      },
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 3",
        completed: false
      },
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 4",
        completed: false
      },
    ],
    completion: function() {
      this.findCompletion();
    }
  },
  {
    title: "Title 2",
    subtitle: "Subtitle 2",
    lessonCount: 3,
    lessons: [
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 5",
        completed: true
      },
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 6",
        completed: true
      },
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 7",
        completed: true
      }
    ],
    completion: function() {
      this.findCompletion();
    }
  }
];

function findCompletion(lessons) {
  let lessonCompletion = 1;
  let completedLessons = lessons.filter(lesson => lesson.completed === true)
    .length;
  let totalLessons = lessons.length;
  lessonCompletion = (completedLessons / totalLessons) * 100;
  return lessonCompletion;
}
```

**Workouts.js**

```
import WorkoutCategoryData from "./data/WorkoutCategoryData";


 {WorkoutCategoryData.map(cat => {
            let currentCompletion = cat.completion;
            console.log(currentCompletion);
            return (
              <View style={styles.workoutContainer} key={cat.title}>
                <View style={styles.workoutProgress}>
                  <AnimatedCircularProgress
                    size={50}
                    width={5}
                    rotation={0}
                    fill={cat.completion}
                    tintColor={Colors.primary}
                    backgroundColor="#dddddd"
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.workoutText}>
                  <Text style={styles.workoutTitle}>{cat.title}</Text>
                  {cat.subtitle ? (
                    <Text style={styles.workoutSubtitle}>{cat.subtitle}</Text>
                  ) : null}
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          })}
```

I'm hoping to get an Integer number I can then pass in as a prop in a component for a progress indicator. Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Where’s the `console.log`? And the call to the `completions`?

Comment: added that to the code now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating `completion` like that is a bad sign – mixing data and common implementation and so on. Consider giving your objects a type (name it what it actually represents, like `Course`, not `Thing`):

```
class Thing {
  constructor(data) {
    this.title = data.title;
    this.subtitle = data.subtitle;
    this.lessonCount = data.lessonCount;
    this.lessons = data.lessons;
  }

  getCompletion() {
    let completedLessons = this.lessons.filter(lesson => lesson.completed).length;
    let totalLessons = this.lessons.length;
    return (completedLessons / totalLessons) * 100;
  }
}

export default [
  {
    title: "Title 1",
    subtitle: "Subtitle 1",
    lessonCount: 4,
    lessons: [
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 1",
        completed: true
      },
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 2",
        completed: true
      },
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 3",
        completed: false
      },
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 4",
        completed: false
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Title 2",
    subtitle: "Subtitle 2",
    lessonCount: 3,
    lessons: [
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 5",
        completed: true
      },
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 6",
        completed: true
      },
      {
        title: "Lesson Name 7",
        completed: true
      },
    ],
  },
].map(data => new Thing(data));
```

Then you use it with `fill={cat.getCompletion()}`. Since it’s a function, it needs to be called.

(Also, do you really need `lessonCount`, considering it appears to be `lessons.length`?)

Another option that makes sense is not requiring this function to be a method:

```
let getCompletion = ({lessons}) => {
  let completedLessons = lessons.filter(lesson => lesson.completed).length;
  let totalLessons = lessons.length;
  return (completedLessons / totalLessons) * 100;
};
```

```
<AnimatedCircularProgress
  size={50}
  width={5}
  rotation={0}
  fill={getCompletion(cat)}
  tintColor={Colors.primary}
  backgroundColor="#dddddd"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a go. And no `lessonCount` is going to be replaced like this also, its just for initial implementation.

Answer (score 0):

when you call completion, you might want to return the result.

```
completion: function() {
      return this.findCompletion();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @David Koe said you need to `return`. However you are passing a reference to the function instead of invoking it - Please try `let currentCompletion = cat.completion();` in Workouts.js and if the rest of your code is working as you expect it should return the result.